# Abrir ventana desde un MenuItem en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy aprendiendo a moverme en el entorno de JavaFX y ya hice todas las 
ventanas que necesito, pero aun no puedo conectarlas entre si.
Es decir por ejemplo, desde la ventana inicial `VentanaMaestra.fxml` tocar en la barra de menu, tocar Autos, y asi llamar a la ventana `AutosVentana.fxml`
Este es el `VentanaMaestraController.java`

```
package pantallas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 *
 * @author leandrocotarelo
 */
public class VentanaMaestraController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.MenuItem exit;
    @FXML
    private javafx.scene.control.MenuItem btn_Autos;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    public void cerrarApp(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
    }


    }      


Este es el AutosVentanaController.java`package pantallas;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author leandrocotarelo
 */
public class AutosVentanaController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello debes crear una nueva ventana y cerrar la anterior.

Para desplegar la nueva ventana puedes usar estos metodo:

```
public Parent cargarFXML(String rutaFXML) {

    Parent root = null;

    try {
       root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(rutaFXML));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VentanaImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return root;
}

 public void nuevaVentana(String rutaFXML){
   Stage stage = new Stage();
   stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);


   Scene scene = new Scene(this.cargarFXML(rutaFXML));
   scene.setFill(null);

   stage.setTitle("Sistema para el Tratamiento de Datos XML");
   stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/stdxml/recursos/icono-stdxml250.png").toExternalForm()));


   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.setResizable(false);
   stage.sizeToScene();
   stage.show();
}
```

Para cerrar la ventana anterior puedes aplicar este metodo

```
public void cerrarVentana(Node nodo){
   Stage stg = (Stage) nodo.getScene().getWindow();
   stg.close();
}
```

y para ejecutarlos te dejo otro ejemplo:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         Ventana ventana = new VentanaImpl();
                         ventana.nuevaVentana("/stdxml/vista/Dashboard.fxml");

                         ventana.cerrarVentana(splash);

                     }
                 });
```